# powershell.exe tab completion - list alternatives?

Tags: powershell, tab-completion

I've never really used PowerShell before, and playing with it a bit, it looks like it uses cmd.exe's style of tab completion (fill in the first likely candidate, and then you can use tab to cycle through other alternatives). I'd much prefer the way e.g. bash works, where if there are multiple candidates, it shows a list of them.

Is there an easy way to turn this on, by any chance?

Comment: »Turning this on« would imply that there would be such functionality which – to my knowledge – is not the case. Also, while the built-in tab completion is extendable to some degree it merely returns a list of possible matches (and it gets called only once for a certain line of input, so the »double-tap Tab« won't be implemented easily).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I have seen this implemented with an add-on called [PowerTab](https://github.com/jasonmarcher/PowerTab) ([original post](http://mow001.blogspot.com/2006/10/powershell-tabcompletion-part-5.html)).  For script editing there are some editors that support this sort of drop down Intellisense.  Check out the free [PowerGUI](http://powergui.org/index.jspa) editor.

Answer (score 1):

You want PSReadline: https://github.com/lzybkr/psreadline

It includes many completion and shell experiences you might expect from bash, etc.