# Can I make powershell tab complete show me all options, rather than picking a specific one?

Tags: powershell, tab-completion

In Powershell, if I type:

```
install-<tab>
```

Powershell tab completion will complete with a single command that starts with `install-`

```
Install-Package
```

And I can hit <kbd>Tab</kbd> again to see different completions.

Is it possible to have Powershell show all options that start with what I typed, like Linux or Unix shell? Eg, if I type:

```
install-<tab>
```

I get:

```
Install-Package
Install-PackageProvider
Install-Script
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to make PowerShell tab completion work like Bash](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8264655/how-to-make-powershell-tab-completion-work-like-bash)

Answer (score 51, accepted):

[`PSReadLine`](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/mt560330.aspx) has a feature like this called `MenuComplete`. Instead of <kbd>Tab</kbd>, press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd><space></kbd>:

[image: EmacsModeTabCompletionWithPSReadLine]

You can bind the `MenuComplete` function to <kbd>Tab</kbd> with [`Set-PSReadLineKeyHandler`](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/mt548466.aspx):

```
Set-PSReadlineKeyHandler -Chord Tab -Function MenuComplete
```

Comment: Thanks Mathias!  Is there any way to make this behavior default?

Comment: @mikemaccana Yes you can! Updated answer

Comment: @Wes Not necessary, a single-key chord is still a valid chord. Are you having problems using `-Chord Tab` instead of `-Key Tab` with a specific version of powershell and/or PSReadLine?

Comment: Add it to your $PROFILE (specifically I'd recommend $PROFILE.CurrentUserAllHosts)

 ....  @Mathias Not sure what was in my first comment, submitted it accidentally

Comment: @Wes I'm not sure who you're talking to, but if you have suggestions for specific improvements to my answer, feel free to let me know, or [suggest an edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/39222449/edit). If you would like to post an additional/alternative answer, use the text box below :)

Comment: @MathiasR.Jessen Is there any differentiating reason for using `-Chord` here instead of `-Key`? At a glance, I appear to get the same result/behavior either way. Is the reasoning just that the `-Key` param is seemingly redundant given that `-Chord` appears to handle the single keystroke case just as well (in addition to handling the multiple keystroke case, of course)? I suppose one could avoid using `-Key` at all, and instead resolve to consistent use `-Chord` for all bindings?

Comment: @CoryGross `Key` is an alias for the `-Chord` parameter (see `Get-Command Set-PSReadLineKeyHandler |% Parameters |% Chord`). When you invoke `Set-PSReadLineKeyHandler -Key ...`, PowerShell actually interprets it as `Set-PSReadLineKeyHandler -Chord ...`