# Tab completion with respect to one file type

Tags: powershell-4.0, tab-completion

How is it possible to restrict the tab completion to a specific file type? I think of an additional function `x` in powershell which only lists `.tex` files and starts the default or a specified program. I would like to type `x doc` to the shell, hit the tab key and ps complete it to `x document.tex` without respect to `document.aux, ...`. Do you have an idea?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to make PowerShell tab completion work like Bash](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8264655/1630171).

Comment: Thanks for the link. It is not a duplicate, because I want to restrict to a special extension and want PS to look only at eg. `.tex` files when doing its completion.