# Powershell 5 PSReadLine autocompletion how to ignore batch files (.cmd/.bat)

Tags: powershell, autocomplete

I use auto-complete heavily...

When I invoke the auto-completion with tab key...
Powershell also includes any files from the current folder
or in the current path in the autocomplete list

How can I configure Powershell to ignore these files
(eg. auto-complete only with Powershell commands/functions)

Comment: I think you would need to implement your own KeyHandler event for `Tab` / `Shift+Tab`.  I'm unsure how to view PSReadLine's current implementation since their module doesn't give you that much insight with `Get-PSReadLineKeyHandler`, but I'm sure the [implementation is here somewhere](https://github.com/lzybkr/PSReadLine/tree/master/PSReadLine)

Comment: thanks... it seems a lot of work just to activate a simple configuration that should be present as an option... ;-)

Comment: It appears I may be wrong.  [Here's an answer that should help you](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8264655/how-to-make-powershell-tab-completion-work-like-bash/37715242#37715242).  Try this: `Set-PSReadlineKeyHandler -Key Tab -Function` ALT+SPACE (to trigger intellisense)

Comment: thanks... I already use Tab-as-Alt+Space... that is for purpouse.. very useful.. but not what I asked...

Comment: You misunderstand my comment. Press alt+tab for the function parameter. Tab completion is not the same as invoking intellisense

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion... I know what Intellisense is... I've done programming in VB and in C#... but what I'm asking is if there are any way of tell powershell yo not getting the files in the current folder... or in path... when asking for auto-completion...

Answer (score 2):

There is no simple way to get the behavior you're looking for.

At best, you can define your own function named `TabExpansion2` and either fully implement tab completion yourself (definitely not recommended) or filter the results returned from the default implementation of `TabExpansion2`.

I recall discussing this idea recently, I thought there might even be an open issue, but I didn't see it after a quick search [here](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q=is%3Aissue+is%3Aopen+sort%3Aupdated-desc+completion+).

I don't know the exact history, but at one point we did implement the behavior you're wanting. It did break some tests, and I think some people preferred seeing effectively useless completions over no completions, perhaps it was reassuring that completions were still working.

At any rate, I think it's a reasonable feature request, I'd suggestion opening an issue if you can't find one.

Comment: Thanks... it seems too much work for a thing that should be present as a configuration option... I realy don't wanna use the boxing glove to kill the flea! ;-) Thanx

Comment: An issue was opened recently, feel free to chime in here: https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/8092